# Receive Docx in Azure Function and return plain text

Tags: c#, ms-word, azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure function to receive a `.doc` file from a http request and return it as plain text. Has anyone had any success with this, examples?

I have tried reading the req.body to string and then converting this directly to a document but the read end up as empty string.

```
string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();

WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
       WordprocessingDocument.Open(requestBody, true);
```

Any help for a noob would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did u successfully receive `.doc` file in function?

Comment: A *.doc file is proprietary binary file format. It looks like you're using the Open XML SDK, which works with Word Open XML docx file format, but NOT with doc.

Comment: Was able to receive this yes and create the fiel but not pull out the text. May have to look at another way of extracting this.